# Array to string conversion when deleting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class, dynamic

Hi I have an Dynamic delete query that I have used before so I know it works, but for some reason when I want to delete a user it keeps saying array to string conversion can you guys help me out.

Dynamic Delete Query:

```
public function deleteRow($tabel,$columns,$values)
{
      $this->setQuery('DELETE FROM '.$tabel.' WHERE '.$columns .' = '. $values);

      $this->setStmt($this->getConn()->prepare($this->getQuery()));
      $this->setStmt($this->getStmt()->execute());
      return $this->getQuery();
}
```

Then I have a function that fills in the user info and execute the query:

```
public function MedewerkerDelete()
{
    $query = new Query();

    $tabel = 'medewerkers'; //welke tabellen zijn er nodig in dit geval is dat customers die hebben we nodig om gebruikers te registreren.
    $columns = array('medewerker_naam', 'medewerker_achternaam','account_id'); //welke gegevens moeten er in de customers tabel komen die komen in deze array te staan alle kolommen dus.

    $tabel2 = 'account';
    $columns2 = array('account_wachtwoord', 'account_email','account_rol');

    echo '

        <form method = "POST"> <!--hier komt het formulier waarmee alle gegevens worden doorgestuurd.-->
        <p>Medewerker Verwijderen</p>
        <label for="medewerker_naam">Naam</label>
        <input type="text" name="medewerker_naam" value=" ' . $_SESSION['vNaam'] . '  "><br>
        <label for="medewerker_achternaam">Achternaam</label>
        <input type="text" name="medewerker_achternaam" value=" ' . $_SESSION['aNaam'] . '  "><br>
        <label for="account_wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label>
        <input type="password" name="account_wachtwoord"><br>
        <label for="account_email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="account_email" value=" ' . $_SESSION['eMail'] . '  "><br>
        <label for="account_rol">Rol</label>
        <input type="text" name="account_rol">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_medewerkers_delete" value="delete">

        </form>

    ';


    if (isset($_POST['submit_medewerkers_delete'])) //als het formulier is ingevuld en verzonden wordt zet dan alle waardes die zijn ingevuld in een array dat is dus de $values.
    {
        $values2 = array(md5($_POST['account_wachtwoord']), $_POST['account_email'],$_POST['account_rol']);
        $query->deleteRow($tabel2, $columns2, $values2);
        $last_id = $query->getConn()->lastInsertId();
        $values = array($_POST['medewerker_naam'],$_POST['medewerker_achternaam'],$last_id); //hier staan alle ingevulde waardes zoals naam is pieter.
        $query->deleteRow($tabel,$columns,$values); //als alles is ingevuld en verstuurd zorg er dan voor dat alle benodigde gegevens zoals tabel kolom en ingevulde waardes worden meegegeven aan de createquery functie en voer het vervolgens uit.
        var_dump($values);
        var_dump($query->getQuery());
    }

}
```

Hope you guys can help me out. I cant figure it out.

Comment: Do you understand that `$columns` is array.

Comment: yes I do understand that

Comment: the parameter 'colomns' and 'values' of function deleteRow() are arrays. that is your query is: 'DELETE FROM medewerkers WHERE  array('medewerker_naam', 'medewerker_achternaam','account_id') = array($_POST['medewerker_naam'],$_POST['medewerker_achternaam'],$last_id); . which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Well... in order for the function deleteRow() to work both variables `$columns` and `$values` must be strings.
You pass arrays.
See
`$values2=array(md5($_POST['account_wachtwoord']),$_POST['account_email'],$_POST['account_rol']);
$columns2 = array('account_wachtwoord', 'account_email','account_rol');`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending $columns and values as arrays:

```
$columns = array('medewerker_naam', 'medewerker_achternaam','account_id');
$values2 = array(md5($_POST['account_wachtwoord']), $_POST['account_email'],$_POST['account_rol']);
```

Then you try to concat this array in a string:

```
$this->setQuery('DELETE FROM '.$tabel.' WHERE '.$columns .' = '. $values);
$values2 = '(' . md5($_POST['account_wachtwoord']) . ', ' . $_POST['account_email'] . ',' . $_POST['account_rol'] . ')';
```

This is trowing the error. Try seting $columns and $columns2 as strings:

```
$columns = '(medewerker_naam, medewerker_achternaam, account_id)';
```

Comment: Array to string conversion iC:\wamp64\www\Examen\Classes\Query.php on line 129
1 0.0013 248776 {main}( ) ...\medewerkers.php:0
2 0.0101 414024 Medewerkers->MedewerkerDelete( ) ...\medewerkers.php:16
3 0.6061 424592 Query->deleteRow( ) ...\Medewerkers.php:138
 C:\wamp64\www\Examen\Classes\Medewerkers.php:139:
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'admin  ' (length=7)
  1 => string 'admin  ' (length=7)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)
C:\wamp64\www\Examen\Classes\Medewerkers.php:140:string 'DELETE FROM medewerkers WHERE (medewerker_naam, medewerker_achternaam, account_id) = Array' (length=90)

Comment: Apparently now $values is the array throwing the error, you cannot concatenate strings and arrays, $values must be a string too.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a variable number of columns and therefore conditions, it would mean building the statement dynamically...

```
function deleteRow($tabel,$columns,$values)
{
    $conditions = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $ind => $column ) {
        $conditions[] = $column.'="'.$values[$ind].'"';
    }
    $query = 'DELETE FROM '.$tabel.' WHERE '.implode(' and ',$conditions);

    $this->setQuery($query);
    $this->setStmt($this->getConn()->prepare($this->getQuery()));
    $this->setStmt($this->getStmt()->execute());
    return $this->getQuery();
}
```

What this does is build a list of each separate condition, so something like `account_email="some@email.address"` and then add them all together using `implode()` to put the `and` between each one.  This is then built into the overall query...

```
DELETE FROM account WHERE account_wachtwoord="a" and account_email="b" and account_rol="c"
```

It may also be possible to use bind values depending on how your other methods work using...

```
function deleteRow($tabel,$columns,$values)
{
    $conditions = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $ind => $column ) {
        $conditions[] = $column.'=?';
    }
    $query = 'DELETE FROM '.$tabel.' WHERE '.implode(' and ',$conditions);

    $this->setQuery($query);
    $this->setStmt($this->getConn()->prepare($this->getQuery()));
    $this->setStmt($this->getStmt()->execute($values));
    return $this->getQuery();
}
```